# DEBUG level logs are not printing even after updating the logger level in application.yaml

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j, spring-logback, jul-to-slf4j

The DEBUG logs are not getting printed even after updating the log level in my application.yaml.

application.yaml

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: DEBUG
```

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

LOGS

```
[main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.FooRepositoryTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
[main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.FooRepositoryTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
[main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.FooRepositoryTest]: FooRepositoryTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there any loggers specific to package structure specified in your YAML? If yes, then those will override the ROOT value.